# Narrow down a Union Type through conditionals

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Say I have the following types:

```
type MyCustomAction = {|
  type: "MY_CUSTOM_ACTION",
  payload: string
|}

type MyCustomAction2 = {|
  type: "MY_CUSTOM_ACTION2",
  data: number
|}

type CustomAction = MyCustomAction2 | MyCustomAction


const MyCustomFunction = (action: CustomAction): void => {
  const type = action.type

  if (type === "MY_CUSTOM_ACTION") {
    let payload = action.payload
  } else if (type === "MY_CUSTOM_ACTION2") {
    let data = action.data
  }
}
```

This fails with:

```
21:         let payload = action.payload                                 ^ Cannot get `action.payload` because property `payload` is missing in `MyCustomAction2` [1].
References:
17:     const MyCustomFunction = (action: CustomAction): void => {
                                          ^ [1]
23:         let data = action.data                              ^ Cannot get `action.data` because property `data` is missing in `MyCustomAction` [1].
References:
17:     const MyCustomFunction = (action: CustomAction): void => {
                                          ^ [1]
```

Link to try flow: https://flow.org/try/#0FDAuE8AcFMAIFlwGECuBnUB7AtgQQMagCWmAdrALywDeAPsLLBDAFywBE8AmgPpICqAZQAqAeXg9cSYQElRAOXYAaBrEgBDcABtM6gCZsMAJyKkA5sFoBfVYzBQ4iVBhwFiZAEyUa9Rn-8BgUEBzNBsnLwCIuKS0nLyHsq2wSmpjHrqoOpspCjYAEbQRslppQHWycmhsM5YeIQk5FRO6HVujV6+AS0u9e6kIMn4ZBgIyK04AGIopA1k3gAU6nOkbLWuKwCUbABumER6lAB8NCWww6Sj1VTL-QB0oSCBRABmsAvXFFQRfEJiElJZAp2JtTsEtNBQGpNDp9N5bo07hptLo9GcrLBoFo0HBXu9Pt9uL9ogC4gpEqDqGdGBCoRksvCVnd6ep0ckbMAgA

Is it possible to toggle types like this? Why can't flow detect that MyCustomAction will always have a payload?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem in flow compiler, but if you use object fields directly it works fine :)

```
type MyCustomAction = {|
  type: "MY_CUSTOM_ACTION",
  payload: string
|}

type MyCustomAction2 = {|
  type: "MY_CUSTOM_ACTION2",
  data: number
|}

type CustomAction = MyCustomAction2 | MyCustomAction

const MyCustomFunction = (action: CustomAction): void => {
    if (action.type === 'MY_CUSTOM_ACTION') {
        const payload = action.payload;
    } else if (action.type === 'MY_CUSTOM_ACTION2') {
        const data = action.data;
    }
};
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAsmAwgVwM4gPYFsCCBjEASwwDsYBeGAbwB9gYZxoAuGAIjgE0B9RAVQDKAFQDycbjkRCAkiIBybADT0YEAIZgANhjUATVugBOhEgHNgNAL7BQkWAhTps+IqQBMFanQZMorDjz8wmISUrJybkoqumogaqwkyFgARlCGFta20DCOmLgExGSUDmh5LoUeNPBIpc4FpDZ4pOjVudgAYsgk9UUwABRqPaxt+a4kAJSsAG4YhLoUAHzUKgyEAGb9g2MAdL4U5JQA5Fy8gqLikjLyh+PLDPf3TSQt6lo685Rbhduv2noA3CsYJYYFBNKhYOtNj1dnZ9kcTkFzqErhEbncHo9miAYDE4p4vqRtni1ICHtZLIDgEA;)